# how to get array of ID image when have array of name image in assets folder

Tags: android

I use AssetManager then i have array of name images in folder "assets/testAssets/img1.jpg,...img50.jpg". Here code:

`final AssetManager asmr = getAssets();
 String[] filelist = asmr.list("testAssets");`

I need get all ID images from that array to use this code from 1 other function:

```
`Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(ID of image have index i);`
```

Can i get ID to use "Drawable" ?! If i can't, can i use any thing to use "Drawable", i must use "Drawable" to do my application! Tks so much....

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("folder/my_image.png"), null);
```

Comment: I thought his array contain the drawable names, but when I look at image path I have found that, he place images in assets folder, +1 for correct answer