# How to get asset images id in android

Tags: android

I need to set a list of images in ViewPager. I have a list of images in my **asset** folder. I grouped the images in seperate folders inside **asset** like assets/images; assets/images1,...... Now I need to get the id of the images (say images1 alone) in int[] array. 
     I got the name of the images(images1) in String[] array. How to get the id of the images in string[]  using their names.

Comment: there is any compulsory, you want to get the data from asset folder

Comment: from asset you have to get bitmap and put on the imageview

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your images in drawable folder to access them. Then you can use this code to get the id of images from their name..

```
 String yourImageName;
 int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(yourImageName, "drawable", "com.example.yourpackegename.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named "drawable" in your project's "res/".

Say you have Images like ...

res/drawable/image,image1,image2,...

In your ACTIVITY, call them by using R.drawable.image,R.drawable.image1,....

```
"Now I need to get the id of the images (say images1 alone) in int[] array"
```

You can also store them in Array and also call them by using the "R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME" as,

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.image,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,....};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I have nearly 100s of images in my folder.

Comment: Ok , so you can call them directly when needed using "R.drawable.image_name" right?  And if you need to call them using an array also, you have to call that "many" times in an array!

Comment: What is your exact intention of using ASSETS folder. To be clear(of what I know), Assets folder in the ANDROID directory structure is used to store some static files such as JSON,Text Files etc., which we can do using InputStreams , Such "getAssets().open("NEW_FILE.txt");" ...

Comment: Also Check this Link,  [get array of ID image when have array of name image in assets folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305979/how-to-get-array-of-id-image-when-have-array-of-name-image-in-assets-folder?rq=1) Here you can refer your images Names through list.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array_images = {
                      R.drawable.image0,
                      R.drawable.image1,
                      R.drawable.image2,
                      R.drawable.image3,
                      R.drawable........,
                      ....
                      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually "id" is created only for the images in the resource folder but not for the ones in the asset folder.

Answer (score -1):

if you are keeping your image in assets than you have to decode it using asset manager .

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    InputStream is = null;
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent)).addView(imageView);
    try {
     is = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");//name of image in your asset folder
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

         // if you dont want bitmap  you can use drawable

       // Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
    //imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

}
```

}

else keep your images in drawable folder in res and use it using R.drawable.imagename